# Could npgsql "listen" when postgresql server stopped?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I'm looking for 2 days now.
I'm using the listen/notify with SyncNotification=true
It works fine.
But what if someone need to restart the postgresql server?
The connection is lost, and the next "notify" will not be listened by the sync notification thread. :(
How can I detect that the connection is lost, and relunch a connection on C#?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Keepalive parameter on connection string, documentation explains:

**Keepalive**:  The number of seconds of connection inactivity before Npgsql sends a keepalive query.

Reference: http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you both for your reply. the parameter sounds great, I will test it next week. I will keep you in touch. :)

Comment: @msmolcic I have changed the response. Now is correct?

Comment: @bgurmendi Yes. I wasn't the one who gave you -1, but I'll be the one to neutralize it.

Comment: I would preferred to come back with good news ...
I use Npgsql version 2.2.5.
I use SyncNotification = true and I get well the StateChange event when the connection become active but not when it is cut.
I tried parameter like ContinuousProcessing = true and  Keepalive= 10 but the connection is not efectue, the connection string is misread and neither the server nor the login and the password are entered in the connection. This may be due to my version of Npgsql, I can not say, the documentation for this is too low. And I can not install a more recent version of npgsql on this computeur : /